# Get values from JSON returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vb.net

So I have a function that makes an ajax call and returns a json string. I am having trouble trying to access the values that I need, below is my code of what I have and a few examples of what I have tried.

```
    s.search().then(function (specials) {
        var returnJSON = JSON.parse(specials[0]);
        var x = returnJSON.location.x;
        var y = returnJSON.location.y;
        });
```

When I check the dev tools I'm getting the following error.

```
 JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

Here is the the JSON returned value after I stringify it.

```
[{"feature":{"geometry":{"type":"point","x":-82.9172080701955,"y":42.55426092899978,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"symbol":null,"attributes":{"Addr_type":"Postal","Match_addr":"48035, Clinton Township, Michigan","StAddr":"","City":"Clinton Township","score":100},"infoTemplate":null},"extent":{"type":"extent","xmin":-82.922209,"ymin":42.549261,"xmax":-82.912209,"ymax":42.559261,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"name":"48035, Clinton Township, Michigan"},{"feature":{"geometry":{"type":"point","x":-84.03589825899667,"y":44.826904141314174,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"symbol":null,"attributes":{"Addr_type":"Locality","Match_addr":"Clinton Twp, Michigan","StAddr":"","City":"Clinton Twp","score":100},"infoTemplate":null},"extent":{"type":"extent","xmin":-84.085899,"ymin":44.776904,"xmax":-83.985899,"ymax":44.876904,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"name":"Clinton Twp, Michigan"},{"feature":{"geometry":{"type":"point","x":-83.93987906956261,"y":42.065412162742234,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"symbol":null,"attributes":{"Addr_type":"Locality","Match_addr":"Clinton Twp, Michigan","StAddr":"","City":"Clinton Twp","score":100},"infoTemplate":null},"extent":{"type":"extent","xmin":-83.98988,"ymin":42.015412,"xmax":-83.88988,"ymax":42.115412,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"name":"Clinton Twp, Michigan"},{"feature":{"geometry":{"type":"point","x":-82.93354923650725,"y":42.60054198222781,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"symbol":null,"attributes":{"Addr_type":"Locality","Match_addr":"Clinton Twp, Michigan","StAddr":"","City":"Clinton Twp","score":100},"infoTemplate":null},"extent":{"type":"extent","xmin":-82.98355,"ymin":42.550542,"xmax":-82.88355,"ymax":42.650542,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"name":"Clinton Twp, Michigan"},{"feature":{"geometry":{"type":"point","x":-83.97095926895429,"y":42.07240087260328,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"symbol":null,"attributes":{"Addr_type":"Locality","Match_addr":"Clinton, Michigan","StAddr":"","City":"Clinton","score":94.29},"infoTemplate":null},"extent":{"type":"extent","xmin":-84.02096,"ymin":42.022401,"xmax":-83.92096,"ymax":42.122401,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"name":"Clinton, Michigan"},{"feature":{"geometry":{"type":"point","x":-84.6015125489642,"y":42.943655651388326,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"symbol":null,"attributes":{"Addr_type":"SubAdmin","Match_addr":"Clinton, Michigan","StAddr":"","City":"Clinton","score":94.29},"infoTemplate":null},"extent":{"type":"extent","xmin":-84.839514,"ymin":42.705656,"xmax":-84.363514,"ymax":43.181656,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}},"name":"Clinton, Michigan"}]
```

I am trying to access candidates location x value and y value.

Comment: JSLint says that is invalid! (http://jslint.com/)

Comment: it seems like this is weird:
 `"y":42
.072400872603282`

Comment: The json is returned from a mapping service. Even if i change it from JSON.parse to JSON.stringify I am still having issues getting the data i need

Comment: Youve just updated your question, and invalidated the answers given! The JSON you now have in the question is valid.

Comment: `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` do *very* different things, like opposite different! Why would you use them interchangeably?

Comment: i know they are different, the service returning the data using stringify is the only way to get the results back and have it be valid.

Answer (score 6):

There are some Strings in your JSON on separate lines. When you copy and paste your JSON in a linter (e.g.: [json linter](http://jsonlint.com)), you will see the errors.

**EDIT**:
You edited your question so you are now using valid JSON.

There is no need to parse your JSON when you already have valid JSON. You can just select the correct keys. Looking at your JSON, you can select your *x* and *y* like this:

```
var returnJSON = specials[0];
var x = returnJSON.feature.geometry.x;
var y = returnJSON.feature.geometry.y;
```

Checkout this [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/jPRVwR) for an example.

Comment: Its not helping the readability of this question/answer with two huge blocks of JSON in the middle :( You can delete this answer now that its no longer relevant (or change it of course

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "parse" JSON returned from a service usually. It is already a Javascript object in the `then` callback.

```
s.search().then(function (specials) {
    var firstItem = specials[0];
    var x = firstItem.location.x;
    var y = firstItem.location.y;
});
```

It should be noted, however, that the first item that comes back in your array of `specials` does not have a property `location` accoring to the JSON example you posted.

Perhaps you were after `firstItem.feature.geometry.x`, but im not sure.

Comment: This actually does not work. firstItem.location is undefined

Comment: updated my code and it's still not working. TypeError: firstItem.feature is undefined

Comment: @pullmyhair then your json isn't what you've shown us in your question, because if I paste your json into jsfiddle and try to read that property then it works just fine. (http://jsfiddle.net/e0c3g1hm/) you have removed all `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify` from your code, right?